# Unstructured data storage and retrieval from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My Employees.xlsx data : I am trying to load the unstructured data to Snowflake and retrieve the same

```
Sr No First Name  Last Name Address Dept No
1 Austin  Jackson Singapore 10
2 Rajesh  Pilot Delhi 10
3 Prashant  Tiwari  Mumbai  20
4 Sachin  Bonsade Pune  20
5 Ruchi Agarwal Mumbai  10
6 Kishore Kumar Kolkatta  10
7 Radhe Krishna Hyderabad 50
8 Brijwasi  Krishna Hyderabad 50
9 Gopi  Mehta Chennai 30
10  Narendra  Mehta New Delhi 40

1. Created the internal stage

CREATE STAGE my_int_stage
  COPY_OPTIONS = (ON_ERROR='skip_file');

2. Access rights
grant write on stage my_int_stage to role my_role_1;
Grant usage on stage my_int_stage to role my_role_1;
Grant read on stage my_int_stage to role my_role_1;
Grant read on stage my_int_stage to role accountadmin;
grant write on stage my_int_stage to role accountadmin;


2. Granting overall ownership

grant ownership on stage my_int_stage to role my_role_1 revoke current grants;

3. Create a table that stores the relative file path for each staged file along with any other related data.
create table document_data(
    doc_name string,
    relative_file_path string
);

4. https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/1.2/darwin_x86_64/index.html
Installed the snowsql

Congratulations! Software installation complete.
Complete the following steps to connect to Snowflake:
    1.  Open a new terminal window.
    2.  Execute the following command to test your connection:     snowsql -a <account_name> -u <login_name>     Enter your password when prompted. Enter !quit to quit the connection. 
    3.  Add your connection information to the ~/.snowsql/config file:     accountname = <account_name>     username = <account_name>     password = <password> 
    4.  Execute the following command to connect to Snowflake:     snowsql     or double click the SnowSQL application icon in the Applications directory. 

5. Connected with the snowsql

snowsql -a XXXXXXXX.us-XXXX-1 -u UserName
passorwd:

6. Using default database

Use database kafka_db;
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.606s

7. Staging Data Files from a Local File System

put file:///Users/austin.jackson/Documents/Projects/Excel_To_Snowflake_ExtTB/Employees.xlsx @my_int_stage;

8. select the with presigned URL : This was done in the snowsql

select get_presigned_url(@my_int_stage, 'Employees.xlsx');

https://XXX-XXX-XXX-XX-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com/XXXX-X-XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

9. Building the stage URL: This was done in the snowsql

WH@KAFKA_DB.KAFKA_SCHEMA>select build_stage_file_url (@my_int_stage, 'Employees.xlsx');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| BUILD_STAGE_FILE_URL (@MY_INT_STAGE, 'EMPLOYEES.XLSX')                                                        |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| https://XXX00000.XX-XXXX-0.snowflakecomputing.com/api/files/KAFKA_DB/KAFKA_SCHEMA/MY_INT_STAGE/Employees.xlsx |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.731s

10. Creation of the table: This was done in the snowflake web worksheet

create or replace table kafka_db.kafka_schema.document_dt(
  doc_name string,
  relateive_file_path string
);

11.  view creation : This was done in the snowflake web worksheet
create view emp_data_v as
select *, build_scoped_file_url(@my_int_stage, relative_file_path) scoped_url
from document_dt

12. Selecting the view : But post which I am not getting any data
select * from emp_data_v  
DOC_NAME  RELATIVE_FILE_PATH  SCOPED_URL
Please help. Why I am not getting the data
```

Did I made any mistake in my steps, else any steps are missing. Please help how can have the data selected which is there in my internal stage for unstructured data.

Else do let me know how to load the unstructured data into snowflake through the internal stage. Is it even possible to load even the external stage. As anyways data gets stores in S3 in AWS for Snowflake

I have pasted the data which is not in proper format, sorry for that

Comment: It sounds like you might be confusing the term unstructured data.  XLSX is just an Excel file that contains structured data.  Save it as CSV and load it as such.  Unstructured data is different from that.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/unstructured-intro.html

Comment: Mike, thank you for the inputs. There is no need of conversion to .xlsx to .csv because we can even load the files like PDF. So in these cases also Snowflake supports. So, there is no confusion regarding structured and unstructured data. If you can't tell about the excel sheets, tell me about how to I load the PDF data in Snowflake

Comment: Are you trying to load the files into Snowflake or load the data into a table?  The link that I provided gives full details on how to load unstructured files into Snowflake.  However, I would think you'd want the data that you showed in your post to be loaded directly into a table, rather than just a reference to a file.

Comment: Well, that's true I want to load the files into Snowflake. But when once loaded how to query is another part I want to know. Loading data into external or internal stages is one part. Querying on that data is another part. So, please help me in getting the same